# How to drag file to the running, but minimized app on Ubuntu 18 Dock?

Tags: 18.04, drag-and-drop

How can I drag file to the running application on Dock?

For example, I have running and minimized Chrome but I want to drag file to imgur or askubuntu topic for upload.

In Windows I just simply drag file to the app on taskbar and app maximize and I can drag file to the browser. Do they possible on Ubuntu 18.04+ without extensions?

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible but what I usually do is, select a file and drag it and then switch windows using `ctrl` + `tab` and then drop where ever I want to.

Comment: @Kulfy Yes, GNOME 3.28.2